# Are there ways to use while and for loops with messages from bot and user in Aiogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, aiogram

I am transfering a program working in console to telegram bot using Aiogram, and I don't where to start with one function. Here it is:

```
def check():
    print('Here are your dictionaries:')
    retrieve_dictionaries()
    dict_name = input('Select a dictionary: ''')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''SELECT * from {tab};'''.format(tab = dict_name))
    columns = list(map(lambda x: x[0], cur.description))
    print('Here are possible directions:','\n','1.',columns[1],'--',columns[2],'\n','2.',columns[2],'--',columns[1])    
    direction = input ('From where do we start? Choose 1 or 2: ')
    if direction == '1':
        box = int(input('From which box do we take the cards? Choose from 1 to 4: '))
        cur.execute('''SELECT * from {tab} WHERE box12 == {box_value} ORDER BY RANDOM()'''.format(tab = dict_name, box_value = box))
        checkwords = cur.fetchall()
        checked = len(checkwords)
        print(checked)
        print('Excellent! There are',checked, 'words to learn. Let us start!')
        print(checkwords)
        id_correct = []
        id_forgotten = []
        id_remembered = []
        while checked > 0:
            for i in checkwords:
                if i[0] in id_correct:
                    continue
                elif i[0] in id_forgotten:
                    print(i[1])
                    answer = input('Insert answer: ')
                    if answer == i[2]:
                        print('Correct!')
                        checked = checked - 1
                        id_remembered.append(i[0])
                    else:
                        print('Nope, the correct answer is:', i[2])
                else:
                    print(i[1])
                    answer = input('Insert answer: ')
                    if answer == i[2]:
                        print('Correct!')
                        checked = checked - 1
                        id_correct.append(i[0])
                    else:
                        print('Nope, the correct answer is:', i[2])
                        id_forgotten.append(i[0])
                        
        print(id_correct)
        print(id_forgotten)
        for i in id_correct:
            cur.execute('''UPDATE {tab} SET box12 = box12 + 1 WHERE id == {word_id}'''.format(tab = dict_name, word_id = i))
    if direction == '2':
        box = int(input('From which box do we take the cards? Choose from 1 to 4: '))
        cur.execute('''SELECT * from {tab} WHERE box21 == {box_value} ORDER BY RANDOM()'''.format(tab = dict_name, box_value = box))
        checkwords = cur.fetchall()
        checked = len(checkwords)
        print(checked)
        print('Excellent! There are',checked, 'words to learn. Let us start!')
        print(checkwords)
        id_correct = []
        id_forgotten = []
        id_remembered = []
        while checked > 0:
            for i in checkwords:
                if i[0] in id_correct:
                    continue
                elif i[0] in id_forgotten:
                    print(i[2])
                    answer = input('Insert answer: ')
                    if answer == i[1]:
                        print('Correct!')
                        checked = checked - 1
                        id_remembered.append(i[0])
                    else:
                        print('Nope, the correct answer is:', i[2])
                else:
                    print(i[2])
                    answer = input('Insert answer: ')
                    if answer == i[1]:
                        print('Correct!')
                        checked = checked - 1
                        id_correct.append(i[0])
                    else:
                        print('Nope, the correct answer is:', i[1])
                        id_forgotten.append(i[0])
        print(id_correct)
        print(id_forgotten)
        for i in id_correct:
            cur.execute('''UPDATE {tab} SET box21 = box21 + 1 WHERE id == {word_id}'''.format(tab = dict_name, word_id = i))

    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
```

There are various `for` and `while` loops, and I don't understand whether FSM can do anything with it (if it can, I'd be glad to get some advices). Maybe there are some other ways to ensure a sequential execution of the function?

I tried to execute it as one state, as well as divide it in various states, however, did not succeed.

Comment: Hello Vlad Could you please provide more in details what your endgoal with the code is? What exactly do you want to extract from the database and how is the bot going to do it etc? THanks!

Comment: Hi!
The program is about dealing with flashcards on the Leitner system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitner_system ). The flashcards are stored in a database as rows. Column[1] and column[2] are a pair of words (in two different languages), box12 is successful repetition counter in the direction lang1 -> lang2, and box21 is the same for the direction lang2 -> lang1. The database can store various tables (=language pairs).
(continuation below)

Comment: In this part of the code, the user chooses the language pair (i.e. table) and then, the direction of words check (default is lang1 -> lang2, in this case he gets column[1] and has to input the string from column[2], reverse is lang2 -> lang1; in lang1).

Comment: During the check, words (rows id) answered correctly on the first try are stored in id_correct. Their box12 (box21 value for reverse) increases by 1 after the check is done. Those answered incorrectly are placed to id_forgotten. In the next iterations of the loop, the user has to answer them, too, but they are placed to id_remembered and their box value doesn’t increase when the check is done. The loop ends when all the words are answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT would be hard for me to translate all this to functional in Aiogram without access your full codebase - but here is what i can suggest for you by experience:

First, create a models.py to contain all your database functions with all your queries. Remember everything needs to be async.

i `assume` check() is gonna be a command /check. Make it more clean by creating a small function for each task to not endpoint with pipelines like this. I used to have this habit before where i didnt, and its a PITA to debug errors or to have modularity in the future.

the absolute start for the check would be something like this:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['check'])
async def check(message: types.Message):
```

Examples would be for your database methods would be:

```
    def get_dictionaries():
    return

    def get_words_from_box(dict_name, box_column, box_value):
    return 
    
    def update_word_box(dict_name, word_id, box_column):
    return
```

also for the lines like this:

```
if direction == '1':
     // LOTS OF CODE
```

do for example

```
if direction == '1':
     directionOne()
```

im sorry i didnt do it all for you, but i wanted to help you get started instead. i hope this will put you in the correct direction on how to do split your code into a more modular and clean style for your aiogram bot.

EDIT: If there is something im missing to answer you, please let me know